# Fit CustomView into SuperView with Autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to create a card view that flips based on this [tutorial](http://www.codingricky.com/flipping-cards-with-swift-and-uikit/). It creates a UIView and adds the card view.

For this I created a custom UIView (with Xib) and so far it works fine. I've added the correct constraints in my Storyboard for the view on which addSubview is called. This is working so far, but when I add the custom UIView it refers to its size in the xib and not the size of the superview.

How can I add the necessary Autolayout constraints to make the subview fit into its superview?

Thanks!

P.S. I've written it in Objective-C but it doesn't matter to me, if the answer is in swift or Objective-C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, what wrong is there. I did the same thing in following way:

1) ProductItemView, a sub class of UIView and created ProductItemView.xib which is having a UIView object.

2) In .xib set File's owner class to ProductItemView so that UIView object of .xib and other subviews can be loaded and linked with IBOutlet.(see image)

[image]

3) In init method (initWithFrame: in my case) method put below code

```
    NSArray *nibViewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductItemView" owner:self options:nil];

    if (nibViewArray.count) {
        UIView *nibView = [nibViewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:nibView];

        nibView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSDictionary *viewDict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(nibView);
        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[nibView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewDict]];

        [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[nibView]-0-|" options:0  metrics:nil views:viewDict]];

    }
```

and finally create object of ProdutItemView and with frame or set Constraints and add it to super view. If you are setting constraint then do not forget to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints property to NO. 
Hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since it's a little bit more clear, what I have to do. For the flip animation I also had to add these constraint for every FlipView (front and back) after it was added to the "StoryboardView" which I flipped.  Furthermore I had to remove and add these constraint with every flip (eg. show front: add front Constraints, remove back Constraints). In the end I had to add these Constraints to the Storyboard View AND the CustomView.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it in code.  seems to work out better for me and makes more sense.

```
// make sure myCustomView is added to the superview
// and ignore the layout guides if the superview is not your view controller
[myCustomView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

id topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide;
id bottomGuide = self.bottomLayoutGuide;

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(myCustomView, topGuide, bottomGuide);

[mySuperiew addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[myCustomView]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

[mySuperiew addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[topGuide][myCustomView][bottomGuide]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
```

Comment: this seems to work partly. I had to add it to my "storyboard view" to fit the custom view. furthermore I had to add it to my customview to fit its contentview. when doing so the first time showing it works fine but after flipping twice (back to the first view) it distorts the content of the customview.contentview.